# Simple 2D Random walk

Tags: java, random

I'm having a problem with average distance in this exercise. It should be close to the sqrt of N steps, but it's lower. Can you help me to find out where is my mistake?

2D random walk. 
A two dimensional random walk simulates the behavior of a particle moving in a grid of points. 
At each step, the random walker moves north, south, east, or west with probability 1/4, 
independently of previous moves. Determine how far away (on average) the random walker is from the starting point after N steps. 
(Theoretical answer: on the order of sqrt(N).)

```
public class RandomWalk{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    double nextStep = 0;
    double averageDistance = 0;
    int COUNT = 1000;

    for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++){
        int moveWest = 0;
        int moveEast = 0;
        int moveSouth = 0;
        int moveNorth = 0;
        double distance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        nextStep = Math.random()*4;
        if (nextStep <= 1) ++moveWest;
          else if (nextStep <= 2) ++moveEast;
            else if (nextStep <= 3) ++moveSouth;
              else if (nextStep <= 4)++moveNorth;       
        }

        moveEast = moveEast - moveWest;
        moveNorth = moveNorth - moveSouth;
        distance = Math.sqrt((moveEast * moveEast) + (moveNorth * moveNorth));
        averageDistance += distance; 

        System.out.println("Walker is " + distance + "\t steps away of from the starting point");
        //System.out.println("Sqrt of N is " + Math.sqrt(N));

    }
    System.out.println("Average distance is " + averageDistance/COUNT + " steps away of from the starting point");
    }
}
```

Comment: Range from <0,1> is bigger than (3,4> so I'd start with making them even by using less than comparison everywhere. I tested it but didn't make significant changes, still... start from here.

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to converge to sqrt(N) or anything like that.  It is supposed to be on the order of magnitude of sqrt(N) or some such.  Or mb O(sqrt(N)).  Math...

Comment: Then I guess my solution is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a few tests on your code with aforementioned change of ranges <0,1),<1,2),<2,3), <3,4) making them even.

And you do it like that:

```
if (nextStep < 1) ++moveWest;
          else if (nextStep < 2) ++moveEast;
            else if (nextStep < 3) ++moveSouth;
              else if (nextStep < 4)++moveNorth;
```

Notice **<=** becoming **<**.

100000 trials of 100 steps each gave those resutls:

```
Average distance is 8.873435509749317 steps away of from the starting point
W=2498906
E=2501447
N=2500022
S=2499625
```

, 
where W,E,N,S are summed steps for given direction during all the trials. 
They look fine.

Running such a test case for a couple of times reveals that there is no preferable direction. You might use other methods to get random numbers, but that would be testing generators, not your case. Your code looks ok from my point of view.

Sentence from the problem statement also gives you a clue:**Theoretical** answer: on the **order of** sqrt(N).

Comment: Thank you. English is not my native language, so sometimes I don't understand all details.

Comment: @zubergu: Nitpicking: *if* I am not mistaken, [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)  `returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0`, aka `[0.0, 1.0)`, so OP's original code partitions that into `[0.0, 1.0], (1.0, 2.0], (2.0, 3.0], (3.0, 4.0)`.

Comment: @TobiaTesan Exactly, and by switching from less than or equal to just less than you make all the ranges even so there is open on one end and closed on another. I'm editing and giving code sample to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line won't work :

```
nextStep = Math.random()*4;
```

the explanation is a logical one. I think it would be better to use Integers for your purpose because you want to calculate with steps, wich is a static unit. Well thats opinion based, but I recommend to count the full number of steps instead of tracking partial steps.

try this instead:

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
nextStep = rand.nextInt(4)+1; //random numbers {1,2,3,4}
```

Furthermore since `nextInt()` generates random `Integer` values you need to use the `==` operator instead of `<=` in your if/else statements.

```
if (nextStep == 1) ++moveWest;
          else if (nextStep == 2) ++moveEast;
            else if (nextStep == 3) ++moveSouth;
              else if (nextStep == 4)++moveNorth;
```

regards to *Tom* (not me, the one in the comments!)

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning, would you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Note that OP has `if (nextStep <= 1)` etc

Comment: @TomWellbrock: now I'm *more* puzzled.  `Math.random()* (4 - 0);` should be exactly the same (as in, compiling to the same bytecode). What am I missing?

Comment: @TomWellbrock: the codomain of `double Math.random()` is `[0.0, 1.0)`. Doesn't the probability of hitting *exactly* 1 or 2, 3, 4 go to `0`?

Comment: @TomWellbrock: fair warning, there is a downvote with your name on it if you continue to edit your answer coming up with random ideas :)

Comment: This answer is (still) wrong for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: Well it already got edited. Why dont you participate in our discussion :P And why should it be still wrong?

Comment: Okay, now that I re-read it it's no longer "wrong", but I find there are three  issues with it: 1. Why would one do that instead of `nextInt(4)` followed by `if(nextStep = 0 ... 3)` 2. In practice it gives results *very* close to OP's 3. Most importantly, it seems to me  thatthe actual answer to the question is @zubergu's: "dear OP, it's not supposed to converge to sqrt(n), just be O(sqrt(n))"

Comment: There are two main differences. 1. The OPs `if-cases` contain wrong ranges, my solution fixes this issue. 2. My attempt is different from zubergu's because I see a step as a fixed unit and therefore want to count it as a fixed value instead of a fraction value. Well youre right that Zubergo also get rid of the "sqrt" issue, I am not font of the Math libary and therefore couldnt solve this aspect